# Why am i getting 500 (Internal Server Error) when settting new src for iframe dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I have a map that indicates the current user's location..that works..but only sometimes and I don't know why. I sometimes get the error "500 (Internal Server Error)" but when I visit the map.php directly then it works fine.

this is my HTML

```
<iframe  id="iframe_map" frameBorder="0"  scrolling="no" width="100%" height="200px" src=""></iframe>
```

this is the javascript

```
$(document).ready (function(){

  //assume I have some code that gets the users current location

  //here I send the latitude and longitude as parameters to the map.php page
  //I then give my iframe a new map with new coordinates and render on HTML page

  $('#iframe_map').fadeOut(3000,function(){
    $('#iframe_map').attr('src',"map.php?lat="+position.coords.latitude+"&lon="+position.coords.longitude);            
    $('#iframe_map').fadeIn(3500);
  });
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't you rather show the server-side code, since it's a server-side error ..?

Comment: Check if url generated is correct for iframe, may be you are not getting lat or long

Comment: @BlessonChristy am 100% sure that i get lat and long and thet the url is correct..because i go map.php?lat=12&long=323 then it renders..but all i am doing is taking that same url and displaying in the iframe..which should work right? and it does work. but now and then it gives the error.

Comment: @Teemu what server code are you refferring to? all i have is all that i showed above..  beside the code to get the coordinates..which is basically google map api

Comment: instead of giving direct values try assigning lat and long to different variables and pass variables to url
var long_value=position.coords.longitude;

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning values of lat and long into variables and pass this variables to the url.
i.e

```
  $(document).ready (function(){

  //assume I have some code that gets the users current location

  //here I send the latitude and longitude as parameters to the map.php page
  //I then give my iframe a new map with new coordinates and render on HTML page
  var lat_value=position.coords.latitude;
 var long_value=position.coords.longitude;
  $('#iframe_map').fadeOut(3000,function(){
    $('#iframe_map').attr('src',"map.php?lat="+lat_value+"&lon="+long_value);            
    $('#iframe_map').fadeIn(3500);
  });
});
```

If the problem is not fixed try alerting the url before assigning to iframe and see if giving correct url.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the absolute path of src. Try in browser debugger in nework section.